# Realm.io database, Does it work on ChromeOS's app runtime?

Tags: android, realm, google-chrome-arc

So I am planning to use a database called [realm](http://realm.io) for a new android app, but before I choose this as the data layer I need to know if it plays nice with the app runtime for chrome(ARC). Does anyone know if they are compatible?

**Update:12/21/2015**

I recently asked if there where plans to support realm on arc in the near future and the answer was no.
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1011

Comment: The real question is if ARC is x86-64 or something completely new. I don't think it does, but then again; the Realm people will know.

Comment: Arc can execute arm, mips,x86 binaries using native client, and uses some sort of jvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm is currently not compatible with ARC. There is a feature request here you can follow for updates: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1011